# Cannot give a permission to users?

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions

I open the "Site Settings" later "Site Permissions" And i give some users  Edit,Approve permissions. but their permission levels are not updated. They cannot edit the page. How can i solve this?

Comment: does the page has unique permissions?

Comment: yes it does....

Answer (score 2):

if the page as unique permissions, then giving permission on site won't help.
So give **permission on particular page** .

[image]

click on share and give permission to that person. then he will be able to see and edit that page. give minimum design permission. To edit the page design permission is required.in on-premise servers share option will be like manage permissions or shared with.

Comment: I shared every pages. and they have got permissions but they cannot see ribbon , suitebar.

Comment: did that page checked in at least once. other wise expect created person no one will be able to see that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving them "Design" level permissions. This should solve the issue.

Comment: :( nothing is changed.

Comment: do u get any errors?

Comment: No. The person that i give new permission level, cannot use the new features.

Comment: He has got approve , edit, contribute , design permissions. The ribbon is missing the user's window.

Comment: Does the list has any specific permission? or did it stop inheriting permissions?